# I want to use dynamic variable that is declared within dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @sql as nvarchar(500)=''    
set @sql='
    declare @N4 as int = 1
    declare @ms as nvarchar(100) = concat(''ms'', convert(nvarchar(10), @N4))
    select @ms
    '
exec @sql
```

I want output as `ms1`.

```
DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(500)=''
SET @sql='
while (@i <10)
begin
    PRINT (''MS_''+@I)
    set @i=@i+1
end
'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

not generating value for @i

i want to put this code in while loop as I want to access `ms1` to `ms10`

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Sql Server 2014

Comment: Post your expected output

Comment: for now ouput should be ms1

Comment: i have to declare variable inside the dynamic sql only

Comment: what purpose you want to declare inside dynamic query

Comment: i am having 9 columns with name sms_1 to sms_9. i want to iterate loop over it

Comment: Is your expected output like sms_1,sms_2 ...... sms_9...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136144/discussion-between-mansoor-and-roshni-bokade).

Comment: yes this is what exactly i want

Comment: Seems like an [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. what is your goal?

Answer (score 2):

Use `sp_executesql` which supports ouput params

```
DECLARE @MS VARCHAR(50)
exec sp_executesql N'declare @N4 as int = 1;
SELECT @MS= concat(''ms'', convert(nvarchar(10), @N4))', 
N'@MS VARCHAR(50) output', @MS output;

SELECT @MS
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use and for that you need to use `sp_executesql` like this -

```
Declare @sql as nvarchar(500)='', @Params NVARCHAR(500), 
@N4 Int = 1, @ms nvarchar(100)

SET @Params = '@N4 Int, @ms nvarchar(100) OUTPUT'

set @sql= N'SELECT @ms = concat(''ms'', convert(nvarchar(10), @N4))'
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql, @Params, @N4 = @N4, @ms = @ms OUTPUT

SELECT @ms
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help

Answer (score 1):

```
Use While statement and string concatenation to get your result :

DECLARE @StartValue INT = 1
DECLARE @EndValue INT = 10
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(500) = ''

WHILE @StartValue < @EndValue
BEGIN

 SET @Query = @Query + 'sms_' + CAST(@StartValue AS VARCHAR) + ','
 SET @StartValue = @StartValue + 1

END
SELECT Query
```

Comment: How you define start and end value..?

Comment: do u know if i wnt to use varible which is inside dynamic variable . as in my question